# In Azure API Management Developer Portal, how can I display an openapi request body schema in a friendly format?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, openapi

I'm attempting to publish a API (using json-api formatting) with Azure API Management by uploading my openapi 2.0 (nee. swagger) specification.  I want to use APIM's built-in developer portal to serve documentation, but I've run into a bit of a snag with displaying the request body formatting.

The only 'representations' available by default are 'schema' and 'sample'.  Sample is useful, but 'schema' just seems to display the 'raw' response schema, which isn't quite as nice as I'd like<sup>1</sup>.  Unfortunately, this seems to be the only way to display the 'description' for a field in a request schema.  This isn't ideal, because that description contains important context about some fields.

Ideally, I'd like to display a table with columns identifying the field, their type, and the description from the openapi spec. I originally thought I'd be able to edit the Operation template to parse and render the information from the schema, but it appears to be passed into the template as a string - not an object that I can index into.

Is there a way to present the field descriptions in a 'friendly' way with APIM Developer portal?

[Schema Screensot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhKpI.png) (Since I'm not allowed to post images yet :c)

Comment: The challenge with passing the sample in as an object is that only works if the content type is JSON based.  Is it not possible to parse it in JS and render it manually?  Sorry, I work on the team but not on the dev portal so I'm only partially useful :-)

Comment: @DarrelMiller It might be possible, but I don't know how I'd even start to do that with DotLiquid.  If there were a way to define custom helpers (like custom filters in django), I could definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to present the field descriptions in the way you want. To do it, you will have to customize the Operations template in the developer portal. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-templates#Product) is an example. Look at the sample screenshot there. It renders *Request Parameters* in table format, rather then *Request Body* in JSON.

Comment: This won't work for our purposes, unfortunately.  The operations only have one parameter: the body parameter, which is described by a schema.  What I need to do is parse that schema (which is passed to the template as a string) and then render that to a table .

Comment: I see what you mean. Sorry didn't understand your question well. In theory it is still possible to use Liquid to parse it. But it seems the portal template doesn't support any json filter, it would be very hard, if not impossible, to parse it as string.